# What are some acceptable translations of "nos viene sucediendo"

Tags: significado

I'm not trusting Google Translate on this one.

The initial context is:

> Y para esto que **nos viene sucediendo**

What does this mean, and what are additional examples of its usage?

Comment: Be glad the moderators are on vacation. Remember the forum does not appreciate _asking for translations_ without any prior research. Too many questions like this had been closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do never, never trust Google Translate. Never.

`Nos viene sucediendo` means `it's been happening to us`. The implicit meaning of this is that is something that is currently happening and has been happening since some time ago.

> No es un buen momento para ti y para esto que nos viene sucediendo.

This would translate as:

> It is not a good time for you and for this that has been happening to us.

What this would mean is that the current time is not good for *him* nor for that thing that is happening to *them*. "That thing" would be a crush, or a relation that's currently happening or something like that.

PS: I see you really like Julieta Venegas ;)

Comment: Haha, yes, I'm infatuated with this song (Eres para mi). I'm Level A1 in Spanish, and I'm attempting to improve my vocab, pronunciation, and understanding by learning songs in Spanish. I won't stop until I can sing this from beginning to end! Thanks for yet another wonderful answer! BTW, OMG Google was terribly wrong on the translation!

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson Never, ever, ever look for lyrics regarding *reggaeton*. You'll decrease your learning.

Comment: If you want to learn a beautiful song in Spanish, I'd suggest Joan Manuel Serrat's _[Mediterráneo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNkcAUAv1kw)_ ([letra](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=68093)). It is considered one of the most beatiful songs written in Spanish.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo By whom? I think you are loosing the point here by adding personal likes.

Comment: In the proposed translation what exactly does 'this' refer too? Is it the (not) good time?

Comment: I explain it in my answer: It would be a crush, or a relation that's currently happening or something like that. It's like "this thing that is going on between you and me".

Comment: The answer is right and explains the meaning but I'd prefer to translate "nos viene sucediendo" as "It's **been** happening to us". If I'm not mistaken is called _Present Participle_. "It's happening to us" is _Simple present_ and it will translate as "Nos está pasando". Anyway +1

Comment: @DGaleano you are absolutely right, I will correct my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think when @DGaleano said it's been it was short for it has been, not it is been

Comment: @DGaleano Also *it's been happening to us* could be *nos ha estado pasando* with the present perfect continuous tense. However it's a bit wordy and I (personally) prefer to use it as *nos viene sucediendo* as implied before, just because it's widely and idiomatically used.

Comment: @Ustanak I heard my first raggaeton song (I think). "El Perdon" by Nicky Jam. I love it!! Also, I noticed something peculiar about Nicky's pronunciation. Then I looked him up on Wikipedia, and learned that his mother is dominicana. Rather than "esta", I hear him sing "e'ta".   :)